# how to get 2 columns from different column family while scaning hbase with jav api

Tags: hbase

I am trying to get 2 columns from 2 different column family and not able to do it. I am doing a time range scan on column bb

```
sc.addColumn("A", aa);
 sc.addColumn("B", "bb");
 sc.setTimeRange(from, to);

 Scan scan = sc.getScan();

 ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
```

I am able to get cloumn bb but not aa from ResultScanner object.

Say column aa is rowkey for that and if I can get rowkey anyhow when doing a time range scan on column bb. Or there any other better way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it looks like the time scan is on both columns - aa and bb

Comment: If i am doing scan on only one column family, can i get the rowkey for row?

Comment: yes. but what exactly do you need? only the key of the rows ?

Comment: Yes...I only need to key of the rows which are coming in that time range of that particular cloumn.

Answer (score 0):

the `sc.setTimeRange(from, to);` sets the time range filter for the whole scan. that is for both column families A and B and for both columns/quilifiers aa and bb

Comment: how can we set the time range for particular column family than?

Comment: you can not. the scan is on the whole table and the time range filter you apply is on the whole scan. you can do 2 scans buts its not efficiant